# Trying to run ardrone_driver and stuck on "Checking AR.Drone version"

Tags: ros, tum-ardrone, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After I installed ROS on my Ubuntu 12.04.4 machine I followed the instructions of this tutorial to install ardrone_autonomy package and  tum_ardrone package:

-wiki.ros.org/tum_ardrone-

When I successfully installed all the required packages, I followed the steps to Run the packages with the command rosrun.

Before executing the "rosrun ardrone_autonomy ardrone_driver" command I connected to the ARdrone 2.0 via wifi. The ip address of the drone is 192.168.1.1

When I execute the command "rosrun ardrone_autonomy ardrone_driver" I get stuck on "Checking AR.Drone version"

Any suggestion how to solve this?

FYI:
I tested the ardrone with my ipad and the freeflight app and it works perfectly. After testing it I pressed the reset button on the drone (leds flashed and the drone reset) because i read that it might still be paired with the ipad.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172978/trying-to-run-ardrone_driver-and-stuck-on-%22checking-ar.drone-version%22/) by [Michael Panayiotou](https://answers.ros.org/users/18803/michael-panayiotou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are probably seeing this error because your computer is connected to a LAN network which is configured to use *192.168.1.x* IP range. This is the same IP range used by the wireless network created by the AR-Drone. The easy fix would be to disconnect your LAN cable (disable that network) before running the driver. The more advanced fix involves modifying the routing table of your Linux machine.  As @z3391384 suggested, you can confirm that the traffic is being routed correctly by using `telnet 192.168.1.1` before running the driver.

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2015-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0